# Configure Stunnel to provide https to web server

Tags: https, webserver, ssl-certificate, stunnel

I'm using standard httpd BusyBox as web sever ran on localhost:80. httpd doesn't support https.

To make connection between some client and my httpd server, I build and run stunnel with following configuration file:

```
setuid = www-data
setgid = www-data

debug = 7

output = /var/log/stunnel.log

cert = /etc/stunnel/cert/stunnel.pem
;key = /etc/stunnel/cert/serverkey.pem

sslVersion = all

pid = /tmp/stunnel.pid

socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

;CAfile = /etc/stunnel/cert/servercert.pem
;verify = 0

;options = NO_SSLv2


[https]
accept = 443
connect = 80
TIMEOUTclose = 0
```

It ran successfully, but when I try to connect to sever using browser, I cant do that.

```
Log is following:
1970.01.01 03:04:58 LOG7[main]: Service [https] accepted (FD=19) from 192.168.0.5:48730
1970.01.01 03:04:58 LOG7[11]: Service [https] started
1970.01.01 03:04:58 LOG5[11]: Service [https] accepted connection from 192.168.0.5:48730
1970.01.01 03:04:58 LOG7[11]: SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[11]: SNI: no virtual services defined
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[11]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[main]: Service [https] accepted (FD=20) from 192.168.0.5:48734
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[11]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[12]: Service [https] started
1970.01.01 03:04:59 LOG7[11]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
1970.01.01 03:05:00 LOG5[12]: Service [https] accepted connection from 192.168.0.5:48734
1970.01.01 03:05:00 LOG7[12]: SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
1970.01.01 03:05:00 LOG7[12]: SNI: no virtual services defined
1970.01.01 03:05:00 LOG7[12]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
1970.01.01 03:05:01 LOG7[12]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
1970.01.01 03:05:01 LOG7[12]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
1970.01.01 03:05:33 LOG7[main]: Service [https] accepted (FD=21) from 192.168.0.5:48738
1970.01.01 03:05:33 LOG7[13]: Service [https] started
1970.01.01 03:05:33 LOG5[13]: Service [https] accepted connection from 192.168.0.5:48738
1970.01.01 03:05:33 LOG7[13]: SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
1970.01.01 03:05:34 LOG7[13]: SNI: no virtual services defined
1970.01.01 03:05:34 LOG7[13]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
1970.01.01 03:05:34 LOG7[13]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
1970.01.01 03:05:35 LOG7[13]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
```

What is the problem guys? And is it possible to use stunnel only on server side and not running it on client side?